# Git Bash extremely slow start up on Windows

Tags: windows, git-bash, .bash-profile

I have read posts similar to this one; it seems my issue is different.

I suspect I'm having this issue due to my `.bash_profile` because when I delete it and open the terminal again it starts up quickly, and it says:

```
WARNING: Found ~/.bashrc but no ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login or ~/.profile.

This looks like an incorrect setup.
A ~/.bash_profile that loads ~/.bashrc will be created for you.
```

.bash_profile generated

```
# generated by Git for Windows
test -f ~/.profile && . ~/.profile
test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc
```

.bashrc

```
if [ -t 1 ]; then
exec zsh
fi
```

I also have a HOME variable in my environment varaibles.

Comment: You are starting ZSH. Any particular reason for that?

Comment: Yes, I use zsh?

Comment: By deleting `.bash_profile`, you are no longer starting ZSH. I suggest you investigate ZSH startup performance.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was using MING64 with Git bash for Windows. It took a solid 15 seconds to load every window. It turns out the .bashrc in %USERPROFILE% was the culprit.

I had NVM installed on my system and these lines caused every terminal window to load for a long time.

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

I commented out the last line and now, bash only takes a second to load. I rarely use NVM so there is no need to load it on every startup.

Comment: for me it was `source <(ng completion script)`

Comment: This is great, but unfortunately this prevents `nvm` from working. To overcome this, I have added the nvm init scripts into a bashrc declared function: 
`function nvm_init() {    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion}`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. nothing helped. Git bash was insanely slow doing ANYTHING, just hitting enter took 20 seconds to get a new prompt.

My issue ended up being page file settings. I have 64GB ram and all M.2 SSDs, so I didn't think I needed so much page file.. I had reduced it to 256-2048M range manually set.. After changing it back to system managed, git bash is back to fast.. but also got corrupted again and eventually it happened several more times.

Now I have page file off completely and git bash is screaming fast.

Comment: An added benefit.  If there is a BSOD and it dumps memory. The pagefile needs to be about 1.5 times the memory size. Otherwise your error gets an ertor.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the same scenario on brand new git instalaltion on Windows 10 and got the same behavoir.
Indeed, renaming or removing `.bash_profile` in `C:\Users\<username>` folder removes bash startup delays. But for some time.
Of course, I had `HOME` env var set.
After restating Terminal and cmd (I tested form both) usually the first run of bash in shell is still slow but starts quicker after some exit/start cycles.

Then I suspected the `.bashrc` file which is located in the ~/ directory `(/home/<username>)` of the linux distribution because by default it is 3.7K and may cause some slowness.
Renaming it I've got the same behavior: if I run bash multiple times in the same cmd/terminal (which uses WSL under the hood) then consequent run become very fast exept the first one.

I've also tested running bash without profile which was slwo the same way:

```
 Measure-Command { wsl -e bash -noprofile -norc -c "echo Hello" }

TotalSeconds      : 29,3953657
```

The consequent run in the same window was quick:

```
Measure-Command { wsl -e bash -noprofile -norc -c "echo Hello" }

TotalSeconds      : 0,2136513
```

So, I believe the real issue is how wsl works with memory in W10 and the page file, and/or caches data for emulation.

Also you should notice that running bash command you actually call wsl, not the git bash:

```
C:\Users\user>where bash
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bash.exe
```

But the git bash is actually called from here:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --cd-to-home
```